# When did the South start using the +es third person, present tense verb inflection in Middle English?

Tags: verbs, middle-english, inflectional-morphology, third-person

In Middle English the Northern speakers started using the +es inflection whilst the South continued to use the Old English form +eð/+eth. When did the South finally catch up with the North and use the +es form too?

Comment: Somewhat related (although it certainly doesn't answer your question): [Origin of -(e)s in present indicative third singular](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299391)

Comment: Uh… Abigael, could you post examples, please? One or two examples each of South or Old English or any relevant dialect or language?

Comment: I never heard of any instance of the South *catching up* with the North… which by no means suggests it didn't happen.f it did, where and what is the evidence?